# Watch for screen size change in a directive Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an issue with using `$watch` in a directive. I want to update an elements `left` and `top` based on some basic information on the page. Below is my code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

var offset_x_function = function(){
  return (($('.map').width() / 2) - ($('#map_display_img').width() / 2));
}
var offset_y_function = function(){
  return (($('.map').height() / 2) - ($('#map_display_img').height() / 2));
}

myApp.directive("plotDevice", function($window){
  offset_x = offset_x_function();
  offset_y = offset_y_function();

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      scope.$watch(function(){
           return $window.innerWidth;
        }, function(value) {
          offset_y = offset_y_function();
          offset_x = offset_x_function();
       });
       scope.$watch(function(){
            return $window.innerHeight;
         }, function(value) {
           offset_y = offset_y_function();
           offset_x = offset_x_function();
        });
      angular.element(elem).css("left", (parseInt(offset_x) + parseInt(attrs["x"])).toString() + "px" );
      angular.element(elem).css("top", (parseInt(offset_y) + parseInt(attrs["y"])).toString() + "px" );
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.map {
  height: calc(100vh - 73px);
  width: 100%;
  }

.map img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="map">
  <img id="map_display_img" src="some/image/path" width="1000" height="1000" />
  <div plot-device data-x="100" data-y="200"><p>item over image</p></div>
</div>
```

While the directive works when the page loads: All `plot-device` elements get a style with a `left` and `top`. When the screen size is adjusted the style is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only **setting** `offset_x` and `offset_y` in the `$watch` callback.  You are never actually updating the element except when the directive initializes.

You would need the `angular.element(elem).css("left", ...)` and `angular.element(elem).css("top", ...)` lines in the `$watch` callback.  (Ideally you would have them in a function that gets called at initialization and in the `$watch` callbacks)

On a side note, there is a `$window.on('resize', function(event){})` event you could listen for instead of using watchers.